# Benchmark Wkhtml PDF converter

Tags: bash, benchmarking, wkhtmltopdf

Does anyone have a wkhtml benchmark?

I would like to compare it with other html to pdf converters.

Is there a bash command for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use time when you call wkhtmltopdf:

```
time wkhtmltopdf input.html output.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks!
Works perfectly fine!